# Target element within table jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this piece of code

```
<div id="drop-down">
<table>
<tbody><tr><td align="left"><select name="selector" size="1">
<option value="Red" selected="">Red</option>
<option value="Blue">Blue</option>
<option value="Pink">Pink</option>
</select>
</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I want to target options within. how do i do it?

I tried `$('#drop-down>table>tr>td>select')` and `$('#drop-down table tr td select')`  does not work. The select name is always different for this reason I can't reference the name.

Comment: Why do you have a `table` around a `select`?

Comment: the cms generates a code which for some reason wraps the select with in table

Comment: Any errors in the console? What version of jQuery? What are you attempting to do once you've selected the element?

Answer (score 0):

With the given markup, `$('#drop-down > table > tbody > tr > td > select > option')` as well as `$("#drop-down select > option")` will work.

To select each `option` to use vanilla js on, use `[0]`, `[1]`, etc. i.e.,

```
$("#drop-down select > option")[1].value; //"Blue"
```

To use jQuery on the element, use [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), `.eq(1)`, etc. i.e.,

```
$("#drop-down select > option").eq(1).attr('value'); //"Blue"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you specify a **name, id, class** or **any other attributes**, your best bet would be to select the `options` by their **index**:

```
$('#drop-down table tr td select option').eq(0) // will return the first option
```

**NOTE that:** 1 will return the second, 2 will return the third and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#drop-down').contents().find('select').val();
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/R7C4H/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have wrapped your code in `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($('#drop-down select')); // gets the select
    console.log($('#drop-down select option:selected').val()); // get the selected options value
    console.log($('#drop-down select option:eq(1)').val()); // get the option by its index (begins at 0)
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PWWBN/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#drop-down select').toggleClass('gotcha');
```